# Correct way of prevent duplicate records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my model I have this:

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

In my controller I have:

```
...
if @location.save
    format.html { redirect_to @location, :notice => 'Location was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :json => @location, :status => :created }
...
```

which successfully creates a record if there isn't already a record with this name in the table.  I think it's good practice to check before inserting a possibly duplicate record instead of relying on the DB constraints?

I guess I should add something to the controller to check?  What's the correct way to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Validations are done by Rails before the record would hit the database. If the record fails a validation, it won't save, and `.save` will return `false`, which will cause the `else` clause of your controller to execute. That clause usually rerenders the page that was submitted, with the errors displayed so they can be corrected.

Assuming that your controller is built like that, you don't need to do anything else. You should, naturally, make sure that any database constraints are mirrored in your validations, otherwise a record might pass validations but produce an error from violating a constraint when it was saved.

Answer (score 9):

Add a unique index in your database.  That way, if something slips through the model validations (rare, but technically possible), the query to save to the database will fail.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do anything in controller.

```
The correct way to prevent duplicate records in Rails is used 
validation in model which you did correctly.
```

Answer (score 4):

Your validation is correct. Just like all the other answers above, however assuming you want to validate multiple fields for example assuming you have a wishlist, that takes the `user_id` and the `item_id`, you need each item to be added only once by a user, for this kind of scenario add this type of validation to your model

```
Class class_name < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of   :item_id, scope: :user_id
end
```

Comment: you can use 

 ` validates :item_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }`
 

regarding http://www.rubydoc.info/github/bbatsov/rubocop/Rubocop/Cop/Rails/Validation

Answer (score 3):

You have the correct way of validating uniqueness in Rails and that is through validations.  You don't need to check this in the controller because that's what the validation does for you.

Remember that adding a uniqueness validation doesn't guarantee that you'll have a unique record in the db.  This is explained nicely in the [validates_uniqueness_of documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) in the api.