# Rails Postgres Query Fails to Return New Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This Rails code is supposed to prevent duplicate records from being recorded by the server within 20 seconds:

```
@transit = Transit.new(tag: params[:tag])
if Transit.where(tag: @transit.tag).where("created_at > ?", 20.seconds.ago).first
  logger.warn "Duplicate tag"
else
  @transit.save!
end
```

However, this is not working.  I can see in my production database (hosted on Heroku) two different records getting created with the same tag 10 seconds apart.

Logs show the correct query is executed on the second request, but it returns no results and saves a new record anyway.

Why does this happen?  I thought Postgres' default isolation level of read_committed would prevent this from happening.  The query that returns no records should miss Rails' SQL cache.  Logs show both requests were handled by the same WEB.1 Dyno on Heroku, and my Puma.rb is set up for 4 workers and 5 threads.

What am I missing?

Here are the two records in the db:

```
=> #<Transit id: 1080116, tag: 33504, 
             created_at: "2019-01-30 12:36:11", 
             updated_at: "2019-01-30 12:41:23">

=> #<Transit id: 1080115, tag: 33504, 
             created_at: "2019-01-30 12:35:56", 
             updated_at: "2019-01-30 12:35:56">
```

Log of the first insert:

```
30 Jan 2019 07:35:56.203132 <190>1 2019-01-30T12:35:56.050681+00:00 app web.1 - - [1m [36m (0.8ms) [0m [1mBEGIN [0m
30 Jan 2019 07:35:56.203396 <190>1 2019-01-30T12:35:56.055097+00:00 app web.1 - - [1m [35mSQL (1.0ms) [0m INSERT INTO "transits" ("tag", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
30 Jan 2019 07:35:56.269133 <190>1 2019-01-30T12:35:56.114572+00:00 app web.1 - - [1m [36m (2.0ms) [0m [1mCOMMIT [0m
```

Log of the query from right before the duplicate is inserted:

```
30 Jan 2019 07:36:12.160359 <190>1 2019-01-30T12:36:11.863973+00:00 app web.1 - - [1m [35mTransit Load (5.1ms) [0m SELECT "transits".* FROM "transits" WHERE "transits"."tag" = 33504 AND created_at > '2019-01-30 12:35:51.846431' ORDER BY "transits"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
```

And here is the postgres transaction isolation level, which to be clear is for a different connection opened after this issue came up:

```
SHOW default_transaction_isolation;

 default_transaction_isolation 
-------------------------------
 read committed
(1 row)
```

Comment: you might need to show how `@transit` is initialized

Comment: Added @transit initialization

Comment: there is a typo. the where should not have `)`

Comment: Can you show the 2 queries in the log and the 2 records in the db?

Comment: I've added the logs and the db records as output from a rails console.   I also corrected the typo in my question mentioned by @LeninRajRajasekaran (which was not in my actual code)

Comment: have you tried extracting `Transit.where(tag: @transit.tag).where("created_at > ?", 20.seconds.ago).first` into a variable and printing out the result?

Comment: I can try that.  I suspect it must evaluate to nil since it does not log "Duplicate tag".  Trouble is I have only seen this once on my production server, so I'll need to create a way to reproduce it, perhaps with a curl script that calls the controller endpoint to repeatedly create transits with the same tag every few seconds.

Comment: I added logging to show the raw result of `Transit.where(tag: @transit.tag).where("created_at > ?", 20.seconds.ago).first` and I either get nil or a recent Transit record as expected.  I created a curl script to repeatedly try to reproduce the problem on my production server and I am unable to do reproduce.  The Duplicate detection works flawlessly each time I try.  Yet I am unable to explain the logs and records created yesterday in less than 20 seconds of each other.

Comment: You may have concurrent data access issue. Read more at https://makandracards.com/makandra/31937-differences-between-transactions-and-locking

Comment: @tkhoynh, agreed this likely is a concurrency issue.  I doubted that since the insert commit was logged at 7:35:56 and the read was logged 14 seconds later.  But since Rails transactions continue asynchronously after ActiveRecord returns, if the commit took 15 seconds to apply it would cause this problem.  This seems long and unlikely, but possible.  I cannot prove this is what happened, but it appears to be the only explanation so far.  Preventing it would require a dB stored procedure or like PhilipWright suggested or a distributed lock like you and kwerle suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was a concurrency issue.

Rails transactions continue asynchronously after ActiveRecord returns.  Anytime the commit takes 15 seconds to apply it will cause this problem. This is long and unlikely, but possible.

I cannot prove this is what happened, but it appears to be the only explanation. Preventing it would require a dB stored procedure or like @PhilipWright suggested or a distributed lock like you and @kwerle suggested.

Answer (score 0):

One way to prevent duplicates in Rails is with validations:
[Correct way of prevent duplicate records in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735454/correct-way-of-prevent-duplicate-records-in-rails)

However your criteria is more complex as it deals with spanning more than one row.
I believe your criteria is, don't allow entry of a transit record if the most recent transit record was created less than 20 seconds ago. Is that right?

Trying to enforce a constraint that involves looking at data from many rows is mentioned as undesirable here:
[SQL Sub queries in check constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179121/sql-sub-queries-in-check-constraint)

A trigger could be used to enforce your constraint at the database level.
One could catch the trigger in an exception.
There's a gem named HairTrigger that might be useful, not sure.

Taking ideas from here:
https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/05/06/when-validation-is-not-enough-postgresql-triggers-for-data-integrity/

Example with Postgresql trigger:

```
bin/rails generate model transit tag:text
rails generate migration add_validation_trigger_for_transit_creation

class AddValidationTriggerForTransitCreation < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    execute <<-CODE
      CREATE FUNCTION validate_transit_create_time() returns trigger as $$
      DECLARE
      age int;
      BEGIN
        age := (select extract(epoch from current_timestamp - t.created_at)
        from transits t
        where t.tag = NEW.tag
        and t.id in (select id from transits u
           where u.id = t.id
           and u.tag = t.tag
           and u.created_at = (select max(v.created_at) from transits v where v.tag = u.tag)
        ));
        IF (age < 20) THEN
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'created_at too early: %', NEW.created_at;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
      END;
      $$ language plpgsql;

      CREATE TRIGGER validate_transit_create_trigger BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON transits
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_transit_create_time();
    CODE
  end

  def down
    execute <<-CODE
    drop function validate_transit_create_time() cascade;
    CODE
  end
end


user1@debian8 /home/user1/rails/dup_test > ../transit_test.rb ; sleep 20; ../transit_test.rb 

dup_test_development=> select * from transits;
 id  |   tag    |         created_at         |         updated_at         
-----+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 158 | test_tag | 2019-01-31 18:38:10.115891 | 2019-01-31 18:38:10.115891
 159 | test_tag | 2019-01-31 18:38:30.609125 | 2019-01-31 18:38:30.609125
(2 rows)
```

Here is the portion of our query that gives the latest transit entry with our tag

```
dup_test_development=> select * from transits t
where t.tag = 'test_tag' and t.id in
(select id from transits u where u.id = t.id and u.tag = t.tag and u.created_at =
(select max(v.created_at) from transits v where v.tag = u.tag));

 id  |   tag    |         created_at         |         updated_at         
-----+----------+----------------------------+----------------------------
 159 | test_tag | 2019-01-31 18:38:30.609125 | 2019-01-31 18:38:30.609125
(1 row)
```

Modifying to give the difference between the current_timestamp (now) and the latest transit entry with our tag. This difference is an interval in postgresql. Using UTC to match Rails:

```
dup_test_development=> select current_timestamp at time zone 'utc' - created_at
from transits t  where t.tag = 'test_tag' and t.id in
(select id from transits u where u.id = t.id and u.tag = t.tag and u.created_at =
(select max(v.created_at) from transits v where v.tag = u.tag));
    ?column?     
-----------------
 00:12:34.146536
(1 row)
```

Adding Extract(epoch) to convert this to seconds:

```
dup_test_development=> select extract(epoch from current_timestamp at time zone 'utc' - created_at)
from transits t  where t.tag = 'test_tag' and t.id in
(select id from transits u where u.id = t.id and u.tag = t.tag and u.created_at =
(select max(v.created_at) from transits v where v.tag = u.tag));
 date_part  
------------
 868.783503
(1 row)
```

We store the seconds as age, and if the age is < 20, we raise a database exception

Running 2 inserts with a second delay less than 20:

```
user1@debian8 /home/user1/rails/dup_test > ../transit_test.rb ; sleep 5; ../transit_test.rb 
#<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::RaiseException: ERROR:  created_at too early: 2019-01-31 18:54:48.95695
: INSERT INTO "transits" ("tag", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id">
"ERROR:  created_at too early: 2019-01-31 18:54:48.95695\n"
```

Short test outside of rails:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'active_record'
require 'action_view'

path = "/home/user1/rails/dup_test/app/models"
require "#{path}/application_record.rb"
Dir.glob(path + "/*.rb").sort.each do | file |
  require file
end

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter => "postgresql",
  :database  => 'dup_test_development',
  encoding: "unicode",
  username: "user1",
  password: nil
)
class Test
  def initialize()
  end
  def go()
    begin
      t = Transit.new(tag: 'test_tag')
      t.save
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
      p e
      p e.cause.message
    end
  end
end

def main
  begin
    t = Test.new()
    t.go()
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
  end
end

main
```

Using someting like Redis has been mentioned - may be better for peformance

Answer (score -1):

This is what testing is for.

```
class Transit <  ActiveRecord::Base
  def new_transit(tag: tag)
  <your code>
  end
end
```

You test code:

```
  test 'it saves once' do
    <save it once.  check the count, etc>
  end

  test 'it does not save within 10 seconds' do
    <save it once.  Set the created at to 10 seconds ago.  try to save again.  check the count, etc>
  end
```

etc

p.s.  Consider using redis or something like that.  Otherwise you're wanting to do something like table locks to make sure you're not stepping  on yourself.  And you probably don't want to do table locks.

Comment: I  do have a controller spec for this, and it passes, so I think it is unlikely to be an issue with the logic.